# if = false, how to?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$a = true;
$b = true;


if (($a == false) || ($b == false)) {
 echo "BAD";
} else {
  echo "OK";
}
```

why this show me "BAD"? how can i fix it?

Comment: is there any code between the assignment and the condition?

Comment: Works OK for me. Maybe there is somewhere `#define true false`? :)

Comment: the posted code shows OK, so obviously this is not the exact code

Comment: cant get you, its showing me ok, please paste the full code, or be more correct

Comment: This absolutely doesn't show "BAD". When I run this code is shows "OK".

Comment: The code you post *doesn't* show `BAD`. Voting to close as this question cannot possibly be answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code will *not* echo `BAD` because the expression evaluates to `false`, yielding `OK`:

```
($a == false) || ($b == false)
↓
(true == false) || (true == false)
↓
false || false
↓
false
```

([Demo](http://www.ideone.com/bAgav))

**Some other error must exist.**

Comment: if (!$a && !$b){echo "all variables has bool-value - false";}

Answer (score 19):

You can use the not operator `!` like this

```
    if(!$value)
       // Do stuff
```

Comment: What you mean by your answer ? It is irrelevant !!

Comment: check  [types.comparisons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) before using `!`

Answer (score -2):

```
$a = "true";
$b = "true";


if (($a != "false") || ($b != "false")) {
 echo "OK";
} else {
  echo "BAD";
}
```

Comment: boolean values as string.. nice… not!